# MAX function in oracle not pulling back expected results

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have table which has a bunch of data. A sample of the data is as *emphasized text*follows:

| DTE | UNIQUE_ID | ROW_DATA | CALL_ROW_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | 11234 | `DCNS=FAILED\|HYPO=` | 1 |
| 8/1/2021 | 11234 | `DCNS=ACCEPTED \| HYPO=NEW CREDIT` | 2 |
| 8/1/2021 | 11234 | `DCNS=FAILED\|HYPO=GIVE ME BIRTHDAY=` | 4 |
| 8/1/2021 | 11234 | `DCNS=ACCEPTED\|HYPO=YES` | 7 |
| 8/1/2021 | 11234 | `DCNS=CONFIRMED\|HYPO=JULY 25th 2019` | 10 |

I have a query that is trying to stack certain data in a single row. The query is trying to pull back: the date, unique_id, and get the first and last HYPO.

```
SELECT
    DTE,
    UNIQUE_ID,
    MIN(CASE WHEN HYPO > 0 THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(ROW_DATA, HYPO + 7, INSTR(ROW_DATA, '|', HYPO + 7) - (HYPO + 7))) END ) FIRST_HYPO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN HYPO > 0 THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(ROW_DATA, HYPO + 7, INSTR(ROW_DATA, '|', HYPO + 7) - (HYPO + 7))) END ) LAST_HYPO
FROM
    (SELECT DTE, UNIQUE_ID, ROW_DATA, INSTR(ROW_DATA, '| HYPO=') as HYPO
    FROM
        (SELECT TO_CHAR(DTE, 'MM/DD/YYYY' AS DTE, UNIQUE_ID, '| ' || ROW_DATA || ' |' as ROW_DATA, CALL_ROW_ID
        FROM DATATABLE))
```

What I am trying to get is :

| DTE | UNIQUE_ID | FIRST_HYPO | LAST_HYPO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | 11234 | NEW_CREDIT | JULY 25th 2019 |

But what I am getting back is

| DTE | UNIQUE_ID | FIRST_HYPO | LAST_HYPO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | 11234 | GIVE ME BIRTHDAY | YES |

Its odd because the data is in order yet the MIN/MAX is choosing different rows. I tried to do a `ORDER BY` at all levels of the query and it doesn't fix the result. It always pulls back the same fields.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your query has syntax errors. It is missing a `)` after `TO_CHAR`; `CALL_DATE` column does not exist; and it uses a mix of aggregated and non-aggregated columns without a `GROUP BY` clause. Please [edit] your question so it will actually run. Also, you are matching `| HYPO` but some data does not have the space between the `|` and the `H`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'YES' is the maximum hypo. It starts with a 'Y' and thus comes last in the alphabet. Assuming that you have a typo in your sample data accidentally omitting `HYPO=` in the row, 'GIVE ME BIRTHDAY' would be the minimum hypo. It starts with a 'G' and is the first in alphabetical order.

You say you want the first and last hypo instead and hoped Oracle would magically know what you consider first and last and apply MIN/MAX accordingly. I suppose what you have in mind is look at all rows with a hypo (`call_row_id` 2, 7, and 10) and of these consider the one with the lowest `call_row_id` first and the one with the greatest `call_row_id` last.

You get the first and last row's value in an aggregation with Oracle's `KEEP FIRST/LAST`.

```
select
  dte, unique_id,
  max(hypo) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(hypo, 1, 2), call_row_id) as first_hypo,
  max(hypo) keep (dense_rank last  order by nvl2(hypo, 2, 1), call_row_id) as last_hypo
from
(
  select
    dte, unique_id, call_row_id,
    trim(regexp_replace(row_data, '^.*HYPO=(.*)$', '\1')) as hypo
  from datatable
)
group by dte, unique_id
order by dte, unique_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab99c199b1c3ce49a2029f0205700e14

Comment: `GIVE ME BIRTHDAY` is not the minimum as it does not have a `| HYPO` prefix.

Comment: @MT0: That is true. As the OP said they got that value with MIN, I assumed a typo in the sample data and forgot to mention this in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my example earlier. This answer works great thank you!